# Django query database and adding users to specific group of objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I a trying to query my Blog model such that it will return the number of likes for a blog post with the `title = example` and `name = something`

```
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')
```

right now I am trying to get the count of likes in my model with this method:

```
   def average_voting(self):
        likes = Post.objects.filter(title=self.title,name=self.name).likes.count()
        return likes
```

and for adding a user I am using:

`Post.objects.filter(title="example",name="something").likes.add(User`)

but my lines are not working I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

**EDIT**
*Basically a for loop that will do this will be:*

```
counter = 0
for c in Post.objects.filter(title=self.title,name=self.name):
    counter+=c.likes.count()
```

My intention is that when a user likes a post with same title regardless of who added the post the number of likes across all post with same title will change.

I was also wondering how I can check if a user exists in a post can I use:

```
Post.objects.get(title=self.title,name=self.name).likes.filter(users=user.id).exists():
```

If in my user model I have many to many relationship such that:

```
posts = models.ManyToManyField('home.Post',related_name='profiles')
```

so I'm basically trying to see if a user has liked a post with that title before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count the number of likes with:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='likes')

    def num_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

as for adding a new like, you can again not use `.filter()`, since that would result in a *collection* of `Post` objects. You should use `.get(..)`:

```
Post.objects.get(title='example', name='something').likes.add(myuser)
```

**EDIT**: If there are multiple `Post`s with the same title, you can query with:

```
def num_likes(self):
    return Post.likes.through.objects.filter(post__title=self.title, post__name=self.name).count()
```

Or you can check if the user exists in the likes with:

```
return Post.likes.through.objects.filter(
    post__title=self.title,
    post__name=self.name,
    user=myuser
).exists()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. For the counting, part lets say I have a course with same title and I want to count the likes of all courses with the same title and return that (That why Im adding the user to the Post object with the same title. Meaning if the content of posts are different but titles are the same an equal number of likes will be returned. I will add a loop function to demonstrate what I mean.

Comment: I understood that but now I can't seems to check if my user exists in likes of the post with a certain title following your response

Comment: @ashes999: you can. That being said, I'm not sure that adding up multiple posts that "happen" to have the same title, is a good idea.

Comment: Oh okay I see so regardless if my many-to-many relationship is established in the User model I can still filter it in my post objects?

Comment: @ashes999: course = post? Exactly where does the `Course` objects come in here? Yes you can, you can for example filter with `Post.objects.filter(likes=my_user)`.

Comment: Yes sorry that was a mispelling. I understand now thanks for all your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried your code for checking if users exist I am getting an error: `AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'model'` for return `Post.likes.model.filter(post__title=self.title,post__name=self.name,user=myuser).exists()`

Comment: @ashes999: sorry, I forgot the `.objects` after `.model`.

Comment: Sorry but I am still getting an error maybe I should just do a simple for loop? I am now getting `AttributeError: 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'model'`

Comment: @ashes999: beware that the `Post` in `Post.likes.model` is not a `Post` *object*, but the `Post` class.

Comment: Yes but Im still trying to resolve the issue seems I will need to use forloop until I find a solution to my problem. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: @ashes999: can you edit the questiond and share the full traceback? I think that might help in determining the problem.

Comment: Yes I will post another question as I am using your method for a separate model but the same concept. There are many fields in there I will post it shortly.